# BoundsError: attempt to access 5-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}} at index [1, 1, 2]

Tags: julia

I have written a code with the aim of solving ODEs. yC is the array of coarse intervals, and fine_solve is the array of fine intervals. Naturally, the initial value of fine_solve is the corresponding coarse value from yC. Below is my code for this:

```
yC = Array{Array{Float64, 1}}(undef, size(5, 1), 4)
yC = [zeros(2) for _ in 1:size(5, 1), j in 1:4]
fine_solve = Array{Array{Float64, 1}}(undef, 4, 17, 4)
fine_solve = [[zeros(2) for _ in 1:17] for _ in 1:4, k in 1:4]
fine_solve[1, 1, 2] = [yC[1, 1]]
```

I am unfamiliar with "array of arrays" in julia, so any help would be appreciated.

I used similar logic with 1-D arrays before and it worked fine.

Comment: You probably don't want arrays of arrays of arrays — multidimensional arrays are better if the dimensionalities are all the same — but if you do, then `fine_solve[1][1][2] = ...`